# How to find the generator of a $\Sigma$ Algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Can you help me with the following?

> For $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbb{a}> 0$, let $\mathbb{a}A:=\{\mathbb{a}x\mid x\in A\}$. If $A$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $\mathbb{a}A$ is also a Borel set.

I thought about using the good set principle and I already showed that $aA$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra. The only thing missing, is to show that $aA$ contains the generator of the Borel-Algebra.

But we've never learned how to find it and I don't have an idea how to do that.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well if you showed $aA$ is Borel, then aren't you done?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I did show that $aA$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra. Just edited it.

Comment: I changed $\mathbb{a}A$:={$\mathbb{a}x$|$x\in A$} to $\mathbb{a}A:=\{\mathbb{a}x \mid x\in A\}.$ One shouldn't alternate in and out of MathJax like that. Just keep all the math notation inside the MathJax tags. That way you don't get font mismatches and lack of proper spacing and incorrect alignment.

Comment: There are several generators for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra - I find it odd that you have not seen examples of some of them in lectures or your book,

Comment: Actually we have seen some, but I don't see how to determine the generator of an unkown Borel set.

Comment: How did you show $aA$ is a $\sigma$-algebra? It is definitely not since, say, $\emptyset$ isn't an element. $aA$ is like a scaled version of your original set $A$. I think your whole approach is a bit off here. You want to show that $aA$ is a Borel set.

Comment: Also, I think you might be a bit confused about generating $\sigma$-algebras. You seem to want to find a generator of a Borel set, but that doesn't make sense. Given a collection of sets, you can consider the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing those sets. We say that such a $\sigma$-algebra is generated by those sets. For instance, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on a topological space is defined as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of $X$. That is, it is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open sets. There are many generating sets for it though.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above you should recap expressions like "Borel set", "$\sigma$-Algebra" and "generator".

If you did consider the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{a}}x$ which is continuous hence measurable and it holds $$\mathbb{a}A = f^{-1}(A)$$ and so $\mathbb{a}A$ is a Borel set because $A$ is.